# jQuery 1.4.4, dynamically rendered select doesn't render selected option in IE8

Tags: jquery

HTML

```
<div class="ph">
</div>
<div class="ph">
</div>
```

Javascript

```
$(function(){
    var htmlStr = '\
        <select id="OptionID" name="OptionID">\
            <option value="">--- Select ---</option>\
            <option value="1">Option 1</option>\
            <option value="2">Option 2</option>\
            <option value="3">Option 3</option>\
            <option value="4">Option 4</option>\
            <option value="5">Option 5</option>\
            <option selected="selected" value="6">Option 6</option>\
            <option value="7">Option 7</option>\
            <option value="8">Option 8</option>\
        </select>\
        ';

    $(".ph").html(htmlStr);
});
```

[Example JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9dtyB/) - doesn't select Option 6 in IE8, works fine in IE9 and FF. Change the jQuery version to later than 1.4.4 and it starts working. What has changed in jQuery since 1.4.4 for this behavior? Any workaround?

EDIT

Workaround - this works

```
$(".ph").each(function(){
    $(this).html(htmlStr);
});
```

[Workaround JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9dtyB/1/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use workaround

```
$(".ph").each(function(){
    $(this).html(htmlStr);
});
```

[Workaround JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9dtyB/1/)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what the problem was with the earlier version of jQuery, but a workaround could be to set the selected value after creating the elements - the following worked for me in IE8:

```
$(".ph").find("option[value='6']").attr("selected","selected");
```

Or whatever you want to do to make that more efficient.

Comment: That is not an option as it is unknown what the HTML contains. This HTML is fetched via an AJAX request and is rendered dynamically. For now I am using the workaround I have posted until the app can be upgraded to latest version of jQuery. Now the question really is about what was changed and it would be nice to know the reason.

Comment: Fair enough. I posted this answer before I saw that you'd updated the question. As far as what has changed, it seems to me the old behaviour was incorrect and the new behaviour is correct, so isn't that reason enough?